# Apache and php5 fail on ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-12.04, php5

I update a PHP 5.5.28-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)

and have apache

Apache/2.2.22

but when run a restart apache2

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 216 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: ap_unixd_config
```

i have a

```
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer PHP install is looking for ap_unixd_config, but Apache 2.2 still calls it unixd_config.

You can downgrade your PHP or, more preferably, upgrade to Apache 2.4.